# Use VBA to Set Pivot Table to Specific Date Based on Another Field

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, filtering

I have tried many iterations that I have found on the web but cannot get this to work.  I have a pivot table that I need to update weekly and I need the date to be set to a variable base on a field in the worksheet.  The date is a filter.  Using the code below, I can change the date to a specific date.

```
Sub Macro7()

'
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("[Test_Data].[Date].[Date]" _
        ).ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("[Test_Data].[Date].[Date]" _
        ).CurrentPageName = "[Test_Data].[Date].&[2020-07-12T00:00:00]"
End Sub
```

However, when I try to set the date to a variable such as a string that points to the worksheet cell containing the date, it errors out, normally stating 'Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class'.  I have tried many different options and different code but nothing has worked. D2 is where the date is that changes.  It updates based on a formula.  I have tried also just hard coding the dates in the cell but that does not work either.  Have also tried matching up date formats to the pivot, did not help.  The field pulls the date of the last Friday, if that matters.  I would be fine putting that into the code instead, if that would help (I tried, I got an error that the string could not be converted to the date).

```
Sub My_macro()
    Dim str As String
    str = ActiveSheet.Range("d2")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("[Test_Data].[Date].[Date]" _
        ).ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("[Test_Data].[Date].[Date]").CurrentPage = str
End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me how to correct this?  Have been trying for hours and hours and just cannot get it figured.  Thanks.  PS--I tried to upload a sheet, but I cannot figure out how, looks like I can only do pictures, so I uploaded that.  Below is the pivot where the date filter is the issue, and below that is a sample of what feeds the pivot.
[image: Sample]

[image: Sample of Data Source]

Edit:  Have shared a sample of the file here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4tzrrue0mggf6om/AAAd6024feSdc9MbCd9IZD0Wa?dl=0

Comment: If you want to share a workbook you need to upload it to dropbox/onedrive/box etc and share a link here.

Comment: Does the date you're trying to set exist in the data ?  Would help to show a sample of the underlying source data.

Comment: Hi, thanks...I am not sure what you mean, but the query does exist in the workbook, yes.  The only issue I am having is getting the Date filter to be set to a specific date.  I tried to have that data uploaded, but was told I cannot as it is confidential proprietary data.  Could only upload what you see here.  I will update the question with a sample though!

Comment: You don't have to use your actual data, it only needs to be enough to illustrate the problem. Unless the concept of "dates" is company-confidential...  ;-)

Comment: I added a sample of how the data itself looks which feeds the pivot.  I hope that helps, as I am desperately needing help!  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you record a macro you will get something like this

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("[_Data].[Date].[Date]"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("[_Data].[Date].[Date]"). _
        CurrentPage = "[_Data].[Date].&[2019-08-16T00:00:00]"
End Sub
```

Even though the macro gave you that code, it will error out if you directly ran it without changing anything.

**Solution**: This is a very old problem which can be fixed by changing `CurrentPage` to `CurrentPageName`

Now changing it to suit your need...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim rngDt As Range
    Set rngDt = ws.Range("D2")
    
    Dim dtString As String
    dtString = Format(rngDt.Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[_Data].[Date].[Date]")
    
    pf.ClearAllFilters
    pf.CurrentPageName = "[_Data].[Date].&[" & dtString & "T00:00:00]"
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

> May I ask you...how can I select
> MULTIPLE pivots on the same sheet and do this to their filters as
> well, picking the same date (cell D2) for all of them? Just repeat the
> code down, subbing in the names, or would something like an array
> work? Thank you again, marking yours as the answer! –
> learningthisstuff 2 days ago
>
> You can do that in loop. For each pt in
> ws.PivotTables and then For each pf in pt.PivotFields :) – Siddharth
> Rout 2 days ago
>
> Thanks....where do I put those lines? I tried a couple of places I
> thought made sense but keep getting errors. I will keep trying
> options, wondering if I need to remove the 'set pt/pf' lines? Thank
> you. – learningthisstuff 14 hours ago >
>
> Do they have the same field "Date"? – Siddharth Rout 13 hours ago
>
> Yes, they are all almost identical. Same filters. – learningthisstuff 11 hours ago

You can try something like this (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim rngDt As Range
    Set rngDt = ws.Range("D2")
    
    Dim dtString As String
    dtString = Format(rngDt.Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[_Data].[Date].[Date]")
        pf.ClearAllFilters
        pf.CurrentPageName = "[_Data].[Date].&[" & dtString & "T00:00:00]"
    Next pt
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

As requested by OP's edit to this answer, since there are multiple pivots, the following changes to the above code was finally made.

```
Sub Sample2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rngDt As Range
    Set rngDt = ws.Range("F32")

    Dim dtString As String
    dtString = Format(rngDt.Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        If pt = "PivotTable2" Then
            Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[_Data].[Date].[Date]")
            pf.ClearAllFilters
            pf.CurrentPageName = "[_Data].[Date].&[" & dtString & "T00:00:00]"
        Else
            Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Sales_Data].[Date].[Date]")
            pf.ClearAllFilters
            pf.CurrentPageName = "[Sales_Data].[Date].&[" & dtString & "T00:00:00]"
        End If
    Next pt
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth, you mad genius you!  Thank you so much, it worked!  I am not sure whatyou did differently other than the date formatting, as I had tried the CurrentPageName as well and could not get it to work, but yours did!  Thank you so much!  May I ask you...how can I select MULTIPLE pivots on the same sheet and do this to their filters as well, picking the same date (cell D2) for all of them?  Just repeat the code down, subbing in the names, or would something like an array work?  Thank you again, marking yours as the answer!

Comment: You can do that in loop. `For each pt in ws.PivotTables` and then `For each pf in pt.PivotFields` :)

Comment: Thanks....where do I put those lines? I tried a couple of places I thought made sense but keep getting errors.  I will keep trying options, wondering if I need to remove the 'set pt/pf' lines?  Thank you.

Comment: Do they have the same field "Date"?

Comment: Yes, they are all almost identical.  Same filters.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Never worked with cubefields, but this seems to do what you want:

```
Sub My_macro()
    
    Dim dt As Date, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField
    
    dt = ActiveSheet.Range("d2")
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    
    Set pf = pt.PageFields("[_Data].[Date].[Date]")
    With pf
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CubeField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        .VisibleItemsList = _
             Array("[_Data].[Date].&[" & Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "T00:00:00]")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, but still will not work.  Same exact error:  Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class.  It finds the cell fine, identifies it, clears it, etc.  Just stops when you actually try to update it.

Comment: It worked for me if the date in D2 was actually in the dataset.  Not much else I can suggest unless you can share a sample workbook.

Comment: Hi Tim, so I did some convincing and have added this to dropbox here:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4tzrrue0mggf6om/AAAd6024feSdc9MbCd9IZD0Wa?dl=0